# Signo extraño ┐ al imprimir interrogante invertido ¿ en System.out.print("¿")

Tags: java

Al imprimir el caracter ¿ me devuelve **┐**

Ejemplo:

```
System.out.print("¿Seguir?") //Devuelve: ┐Seguir?
```

Comment: Prueba sustituyendo el "¿" por &iquest; ó &#191; Tiene pinta de faltarte el UTF-8.

Comment: Hola, ¿Que IDE estas usando?

Answer (score 5):

### Teoría sobre codificación de caracteres

Cada carácter es representado en memoria en realidad por una cierta secuencia de bits. La terminal interpreta esa secuencia de bits para mostrar el correspondiente carácter.

Esto significa que la aplicación que envía los bits a la terminal debe conocer cómo la terminal interpretará los bits, para que se muestren los caracteres correctos.

El código ASCII es un estándar muy antiguo que establece códigos de 7 bits (que pueden verse como números entre 0 y 127) para las letras del alfabeto inglés y un montón de símbolos más. Así, por ejemplo, el código numérico 97 (patrón de bits `1100001`) representa la letra `a`.

Al ser tan antiguo y extendido este código es admitido por todas las terminales, todos los editores y todo el software en general. Por eso el texto "Hola" sale correctamente, porque es codificado en ASCII en memoria como la secuencia de bytes `72, 111, 108, 97`, que es enviada a la terminal, la cual, al soportar también el estándar ASCII muestra los caracteres "H", "o", "l", y "a".

El problema aparece en cuanto te sales de los caracteres previstos en el código ASCII, como por ejemplo el símbolo `¿`, o la `ñ` o las vocales acentuadas, o ya puestos cualquier carácter de otros alfabetos como cirílico, árabe, chino, etc.

Para codificar cualquier alfabeto el estándar actual se denomina Unicode y no se limita a códigos de 7 bits, sino que usa muchos más (pues son millones de posibles caracteres los que puede representar).

### Explicación a tu problema

En cualquier caso, tu problema no está relacionado con Unicode. Lo que está ocurriendo aquí es que tu programa emite hacia la terminal los caracteres usando una codificación denominada `cp1252`, mientras que la terminal los interpreta usando otra codificación diferente llamada `cp437`.

La codificación `cp1252` es la estándar en Windows desde hace ya mucho tiempo. Puedes ver [en wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) que en esta codificación, al carácter `¿` le corresponde el código `BF` (en esta tabla los códigos se muestran en hexadecimal; este número en binario sería `10111111` y en decimal sería el `191`).

Por otro lado la codificación `cp437` era la que usaba MS-DOS, el primer operativo para PC, y que Windows aún conserva para la consola. Puedes ver [en wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) que en esta codificacion, el código 191 representa al carácter `┐`. Esto explica por tanto lo que te ocurre. Y puedes probar que si en tus mensajes incluyes eñes o acentos, también saldrán mal (y puedes entretenerte observando las tablas antes mencionadas para ver cómo todo encaja).

### Solución

La solución más simple es cambiar la tabla de códigos de la consola windows, para que se ajuste a la que está usando tu programa Java. Basta teclear lo siguiente en la terminal:

```
chcp 1252
```

El comando `chcp` (change code page) te permite modificar la forma en la que la terminal interpreta los códigos que recibe. Como puedes imaginar, poner `1252` hace que pase a utilizar la codificación Windows, con lo que ya verás correctamente la salida del programa *siempre que el programa emita los caracteres usando esta misma codificación*.

Es posible que te encuentres otros programa que emitan en Unicode (en concreto en UTF-8 que es una forma de codificar Unicode como secuencias de bytes). Hoy día es el estándar y como he dicho soporta muchos más alfabetos. Para cambiar la consola windows de modo que soporte UTF-8 has de escribir `chcp 65001` (y además la terminal debe usar una fuente que tenga caracteres en los alfabetos soportados, por lo que es probable que debas cambiar la fuente usada por defecto en la terminal, a través de su menú de Propiedades).

Comment: Había olvidado la codificación `cp437` de D.O.S. Qué tiempos aquellos.

Answer (score 1):

Tu archivo debe tener la codificación `UTF-8` que es la que regularmente se usa en las IDE para Java, para que de esta forma pueda imprimir correctamente la información:

```
System.out.println("¿Seguir?");
```

salida:

```
   ¿Seguir?
```

Puedes imprimir que codificación estas usando actualmente en tu proyecto mediante :

```
System.out.println("defaultCharset: " + java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset());
```

en Netbeans por ejemplo puedes definir la codificación de tu proyecto desde sus propiedades:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]